# Multiple Paginations on one Page

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, archives

I have a page template which aggregates multiple CPT's in different areas of the page and displays the first post from each CPT. I'd like to add a separate pagination for each of them. Is it possible with or, preferably, without a plugin?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible!
When i find myself in need of multiple paginations in a page i usually use ajax.
take a look at [this tutorial](http://wordpressapi.com/2011/05/16/add-ajax-pagination-in-wordpress-blog/) which with a little modification can do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking at this in 2020 and found that the link from Bainternet's answer is broken, here is a snapshot of the article on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20110625064315/http://wordpressapi.com/2011/05/16/add-ajax-pagination-in-wordpress-blog